# EFCore Linq Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I've looked through hundreds of examples and still can't quite find what I'm looking for.

```
public class CA
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<SignOff> SignOffs {get;set}
}

public class SignOff
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int CAId {get;set;}
    public bool IsCurrentQtr {get;set;}
}
```

I currently have a search function that returns me an `IQueryable<CA> qry`. I now need to use that `IQueryable<CA>` and left join all SignOffs where `IsCurrentQtr == true` but then I want to select all CA where `SignOffs == null || SignOffs.Count == 0`.

It needs to use the method syntax. Also, please keep in mind that there are actually around 50 columns of data in the CA table with 15 other FK relationships and the signoff table has around 70 columns of data and it's using SQL Server 2017.

Can someone help me write this linq query?

EDIT 1:
FYI, this is puzzling to me too but this is the way it was explained to me. While trying to explain this better, I thought of a new way to state it. I need to select all CA that do not have a signoff record where IsCurrentQtr is true.

Comment: `now need to use that IQueryable<CA> and left join all SignOffs where IsCurrentQtr == true but then I want to select all CA where SignOffs == null || SignOffs.Count == 0.` Your requirement puzzling me! Would you explain it further.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - Does my edit in my question help?

Comment: EF Core suppose make your life easier, if it opposite - EF provide possibility to run plain sql queries ;)

Comment: @Ben Please make me one thing clear.Suppose a CA has two SignOffs where one SignOffs is IsCurrentQtr == true and other is false then will this CA be ignored or not?

Comment: @TanvirArjel - In this case, I do not want the CA returned because it has a CurrentQtr SignOff. I only want the CA's that do not have a currentQtr signoff.

Comment: Okay! then you can follow one of my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to select all CA that do not have a signoff record where IsCurrentQtr is true.

Then your query should be as follows:

```
var caList = db.CAs.Where(ca => ca.SignOffs.All(sf => sf.IsCurrentQtr == false)).ToList();

// or

var caList = db.CAs.Where(ca => ca.SignOffs.Count(sf => sf.IsCurrentQtr) == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: It took me awhile to confirm your answer was correct because there was some code that went a completely different route to obtain the same answer. Their answer was returning 46 results and I was being told that was correct while your answer was returning 55 results. Well, I can now officially prove that your answer is correct and the other guys is incorrect. I actually had the correct answer before I posted this question by using a GroupJoin but thought it was wrong because of the number of results. Thanks to everyone for their responses!

Comment: Great to hear that. Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your edit, you want this result.

```
var result = cs.Where(x => !x.Any(r => r.IsCurrentQtr));
```

This will find all CA that do not have a Signoff Record where IsCurrentQtr == true.